# Sandcastle Help File Builder Can't Find documentation source

Tags: c#, xml, documentation, sandcastle, shfb

I'm building the doc of a VS 2010 C# project with the Sandcastle Help File Builder. I've added the `.xml` documentation generated by the compiler and the Visual Studio solution `.sln` file of the project to the **Documentation Sources**. I have also added the project's executable `.exe` to **References**. However, It is not building. I get these warnings and errors:

> **SHFB: Warning BE0006:** Unable to locate any documentation sources for 'C:\Users\user\Music\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SFML_Platformer\SFML_Platformer.sln' (Configuration: Debug Platform: AnyCPU)
>
> **SHFB: Error BE0042:** You must specify at least one documentation source in the form of an assembly or a Visual Studio solution/project file

What's the problem?

Comment: Is `SFML_Platformer.sln` your documentation solution or the solution you want to create a documentation for? If it is the latter, try adding the `.csproj` instead of the `.sln`. Btw, you don't have to add the xml to Documentation Sources. Nor do you have to add the exe as a reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should only add the XML documentation files as Document Source. The DLLs are added automatically after you add the XML files.

Answer (score 2):

Here the answer from Eric a.k.a EWoodruff the developer of Sandcastle Help File Builder.

> BE0006 means it couldn't find the documentation source based on the
>   project.  BE0042 is a secondary result of that meaning it found
>   nothing at all to document.  What type of projects are in the
>   solution?  If it's a website project, bear in mind that they do not
>   typically produce any assemblies that are listed as output in the
>   project nor any XML comments files.  In that case, you'd need to add
>   the web code providers to your project to get the XML comments and
>   manually add the website's .\bin folder as a documentation source in
>   the SHFB project.  There's a topic on documenting websites in the
>   Getting Started section if that is the case.
>
> All other project types should work.  If all else fails, try adding
>   the assembly and XML comments files directly.  I suppose it's possible
>   the Express editions use diffent project type IDs.  If you can send me
>   the solution file and project file, I can take a look at them and see
>   why it isn't finding the targets.  My e-mail address is in the About
>   box in the standalone GUI and in the footer of the pages in the help
>   file.
>
> One other thing, make sure the Configuration and Platform settings
>   selected in the SHFB toolbar match the Configuration and Platform
>   settings used to build your project (i.e. Debug/AnyCPU,
>   Release/AnyCPU, Debug/x86, etc).  If not, that will cause it to not
>   find the proper output targets.
>
> Eric

[source](http://shfb.codeplex.com/discussions/403768)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue occur when I switched the project's build in VS.NET on my main application from `Debug` to `Release`. I assume it could not longer find the .dll I had specified to create the documentation. I could have fixed the mapping, but going back to `Debug` worked just fine for me to remove this error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to rebuild your solution after cleaning before running Build in Sandcastle.